# Svelte change color of buttons indivually

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have some buttons and when i click on each of them the background-color should change. Right now it changes the color of all buttons when one is clicked. However it should be for each button individually. Does someone know how to do that in?

That's my main svelte class:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import Button from './Button.svelte';
  let empty = false;

  function changeBtnState() {
    if (empty) {
      empty = false;
    } else {
      empty = true;
    }
  }
</script>

<Button label="process" {empty} onClickFn={changeBtnState} />
<Button label="date" {empty} onClickFn={changeBtnState} />

<style lang="scss">
    .main-button.empty {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
```

And that's my button component

```
<script lang="ts">
    export let label: string = 'test';
    export let onClickFn: () => void = () => {
      return;
    };
    export let empty = false;
</script>

<button
  type="submit"
  class="main-button"
  class:empty={empty}
  on:click={onClickFn}>{label}</button
>

<style lang="scss">
    .main-button{
        background-color: #f2eee2;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: you're passing a single `empty` state to all the buttons, you either need to keep a reference to which button is clicked in the parent, or manage the `empty` state individually in the button component.

Comment: @pilchard ok thanks, could you show me an example with a reference?

Comment: Here's a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/436cb527009141768f2def56dc0094f6?version=3.46.2) how you could handle the logic inside each button component indivually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you bind both your button's empty attribute to the same variable:

```js
<Button label="process" {empty} onClickFn={changeBtnState} />
<Button label="date" {empty} onClickFn={changeBtnState} />
```

You need a separate one for each button.

Comment: Ok thanks I tried to avoid it but there isn't a way to use a single variable?

Comment: If you use a single boolean variable then you cannot encode separate state for two different buttons. This is impossible because your combined state has 2 bits of information but a boolean variable only has 1 bit. Maybe you could use some arcane trickery where you treat a boolean as integer but why do that? However you could of course group your states in a single object.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do it's to integrate the changeBtnState inside the Button component.
So the empty variable is defined IN  the component and is different for each of them.
Another option if you don't want to integrate it in one component, is yo create an array of "empty" variables (1 per button).